# Open modal on a list of items with modals in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, modal-dialog, sandbox

I have a list of items and each item of the list have a button that opens a modal.

My problem is that I think I've done something wrong because when I click to "open a modal" it do not work. I've made it work but it was opening all modals at the same time and I could not find out how to fix it.

Here my sandbox with all code: https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-on-list-sjw7u?file=/src/components/TopBar.tsx

My list of items is at the class `MetricsDetailsPage` on the sandbox and the part that I call the modal on this class is done like this:

```
<FiltersAddition
    dimension={dimension}
    isModalOpen={isShowing}
    toggle={toggle}
/>
<Button onClick={toggle}> Instantiate </Button>
```

My issue is that if you open the "https://sjw7u.csb.app/metric/test" on my code sandbox and click on "Instantiate" button you will see the modals are being duplicated for each item on the list, and I want to show just the modal of the clicked item (so one at the time).

[image]

Comment: Can you share the problematic code in the question please.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The code is all on the sandbox, can't you open? :)

Comment: The sandbox you shared opens one modal at a time. Although, you can open multiple modals by clicking on multiple buttons, not one button clicks opens all modals. I believe, your actual app might open the modal with an overlay blocking the interaction with other buttons.

Comment: The modal for each element does open though?

Comment: WRT to showing code: "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also copy the code into the question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time."

Comment: Do you only want one modal open at a time?

Comment: Sorry the late reply everybody, I was trying to make my codesandbox be with the same behavior as my code. :) 
The idea is that I have a list of elements on the beginning. 
When one is clicked it opens "details" of this clicked element. 
Inside each element detailed I have another list of items and on this list I want to have a modal on each element but they are opening all together when I click.

I am trying to make my codesandbow work and I am not managing to mock the server reply. If you want to have a look https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-on-list-sjw7u?file=/src/reducers/reducer.ts

Comment: This is why we need to see some example of the problematic code in the question: both your sandboxes don't compile now.

Comment: Got it, thank you for your feedback! I will update the question. Anyway now the codesandbox is working and if you go to "https://sjw7u.csb.app/metric/test" on the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-on-list-sjw7u?file=/src/components/MetricCard.tsx:563-573 you will see the modal being duplicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the future, rather include the relevant, problematic code in the question.

The issue is that you are including the modal in each iteration and there is no parent state to control **which** modal is being displayed at a time.

I suggest you modify the hook and use it from a shared parent state:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { IDimension } from '../model/metric';

const useModal = () => {
  // store which has been selected
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState<IDimension>();
  const [isShowing, setIsShowing] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const open = (dimension: IDimension) => {
    setSelected(dimension);
    setIsShowing(true);
  };

  const close = () => {
    setSelected(null);
    setIsShowing(false);
  };

  return {
    isShowing,
    open,
    close,
    selected
  };
};

export default useModal;
```

Then move your modal outside the loop:

```
          <TableBody>
            {metric?.dimensions.map((dimension) => (
              <TableRow key={dimension.name}>
                <TableCell>{dimension.name}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{dimension.value_type}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{dimension.doc ? dimension.doc : 'No description available'}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  <Button onClick={() => open(dimension)}> Instantiate </Button>
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
       {/* outside the loop */}
        <FiltersAddition dimension={selected} isModalOpen={isShowing} close={close} />
```

[Modified Codesandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-69352784-ik5i6?file=/src/components/MetricsDetailsPage.tsx)

Comment: Hi Samuel, thank you! I actually did not knew what was "the important code" to solve the problem because I was very lost, that's why I have not put the part of code you've answer after I've edited the question, but is noted to try to improve :) 
Thank you a lot for the answer,  is very kind of you and now I see my mistakes!

Comment: No prob, happy to help–it's obviously easier to see the code in the question, and sandboxes get deleted so future members cannot benefit from your question.